# how to pass the result from one component to another with reactjs hooks?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have two components: the first has a count button and the second will display the result

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

function Count() {

  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={() => setCount(count + 1)}>
        Click me
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

and now I need to display the result inside another component:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

import Count from './Count'

function Result() {

  return <p>You clicked {count} times</p>;

}
```

and it doesn't work, how to solve it?

Comment: This is a fundamental misunderstanding of what components are and how they can be used. You might consider going through a few React tutorials to better understand the fundamentals.

Answer (score 0):

react hooks do not share state between components. but the structure you explained can easily be achieved in multiple ways. to implement it without using external libraries you can use react context API

```
const NumberContext = React.createContext();
```

---

```
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
  <Counter.Provider value={[count, setCount]}>
    <Count />
    <Result />
  </Counter.Provider>,
```

and in your components instead of useState use

```
const [count, setCount] = useContext(NumberContext);
```